# Haskell - saving content of HTTP request in selected file

Tags: haskell, monads

As a Haskell beginner I'm currently playing around the IO monad and prepared simple program which gets from the user two information:

- URL (http)
- Output file path

Then it performs `GET` request to the provided URL and stores the result in the selected file. HTTP status code of the response is displayed on the standard output

Could you please suggest how such code could be improved? Maybe some places when point-free style can be used? I also feel that the part with confirmation of file overwriting is not very elegant.

```
import System.IO
import Network.HTTP
import System.Directory


getUrl :: IO String
getUrl = putStr "URL: " >> hFlush stdout >> getLine


confirmOverideOrGetNewPath :: String -> IO String
confirmOverideOrGetNewPath filepath = do
    putStr $ "File " ++ filepath ++ " exists. Override? [y/n] "
    hFlush stdout
    decision <- getLine
    let shouldOverride = (if decision == "y" then True else False)
    case shouldOverride of True -> return filepath
                           False -> putStrLn "\nProvide other path" >> getOutputFilepath


getOutputFilepath :: IO String
getOutputFilepath = do
    putStr "Output file path: "
    hFlush stdout
    filepath <- getLine
    file_exists <- doesFileExist filepath
    case file_exists of True -> confirmOverideOrGetNewPath filepath
                        False -> return filepath


performGetRequest :: String -> IO (String, Int)
performGetRequest url = do
        rsp <- Network.HTTP.simpleHTTP (getRequest url)
        content <- getResponseBody rsp
        responseCode <- getResponseCode rsp
        return (content, responseCodeToInt responseCode)
    where
        responseCodeToInt :: ResponseCode -> Int
        responseCodeToInt code = let (x,y,z) = code in read (mconcat $ show <$> [x,y,z]) :: Int


saveContentToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
saveContentToFile = writeFile


printHttpStatusCode :: Int -> IO ()
printHttpStatusCode statusCode = putStrLn ("\nStatus code: " ++ show statusCode)
                                 >> putStrLn "Content saved into file"


main :: IO ()
main = do
    url <- getUrl
    filepath <- getOutputFilepath
    (content, statusCode) <- performGetRequest url
    saveContentToFile filepath content
    printHttpStatusCode statusCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the top I notice you could benefit from some factoring.

```
prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt str = do
    putStr str
    hFlush stdout
    getLine
```

Then `getURL` is `prompt "URL: "` (and maybe doesn't even need to exist separately!) and `confirmOverideOrGetNewPath` and `getOutputFilepath` both lose two lines at the top. You'll notice that I also wrote this function with do-notation, it's a stylistic preference but I just don't like to run monads into one line like that, not sure if I have a great reason why. I guess it just feels right to make imperative-y monadic code look like an imperative language would.

The diversion through `shouldOverride` in `confirmOverideOrGetNewPath` is unnecessary, just put your expression in the case-statement.

```
case decision == "y" of
  True -> ...
```

But then I'd also skip the check for equality entirely and just pattern match on the returned string.

```
case decision of
    "y" -> return filepath
    "n" -> getOutputFilepath
    _   -> do
      putStrLn "Unrecognized input"
      confirmOverrideOrGetNewPath filepath
```

I changed the logic to make the behavior more elucidating. If a user actually enters `"n"`, it's not really necessary to tell them to provide a new path since `getOutputFilepath` will prompt them for a new one immediately. The user presumably expects that, given their input. If they type something other than `"y"` or `"n"`, instead of requiring them to input a new path, just check again if they're cool with the override.

In `getOutputFilepath` all I'd note is that `file_exists` should be camel cased for consistency.

Over the rest of your program, the only thing I'd switch up would be the whole logic around response codes. In `performGetRequest` I'd just change the return type to be `ResponseCode` instead of `Int`, and push your display logic into `printHttpStatusCode` (which should probably be `printResponseCode`). Since `ResponseCode` is just a type alias for tuples, you can also pattern match in the function call (i.e. in your original version `responseCodeToInt (x, y, z) = ...` instead of the `let`). And then it also probably makes more sense to have a pure `showResponseCode` and leave printing up to the caller.

```
showResponseCode :: ResponseCode -> String
showResponseCode (i, j, k) = concatMap show [i, j, k]
```

Then I'd just carry the changes through to `main` and reorder things for clarity and truth in logic.

```
main = do
    ...
    (content, statusCode) <- performGetRequest url
    putStrLn $ "Response status: " ++ showResponseCode statusCode
    writeFile filepath content
    putStrLn "Content saved"
```